# How to implement a time slot system in django?

Tags: python, django

```
from datetime import date   

    # we need tuple for integer choices in django 
    timeslot_weekday = (
        (0, '9:00 - 10:00'),
        (1, '10:00 - 11:00')
    )
    
    timeslot_weekend = (
        (0, '10:00 - 11:00'),
        (1, '11:00 - 12:00')
    )
    
    user_date = date(2023,1,15)
    
    
    if user_date.weekday() == 5 or user_date.weekday == 6:
        print(timeslot_weekend)
    else:
        print(timeslot_weekday)
```

> This code works as I am trying to understand how to implement an integer choice using a tuple that has the corresponding time slots. How do I go about this in the Django project? The one thing is I would need the user to select the date first in order to adjust the time slots of that particular time of the week. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This seems like a straightforward selection menu choice, i.e. a `CharField` model with a `choices=...` argument.  I don't understand what actual question you are asking.

Comment: If you want the user to pick the date first, then you will PROBABLY want to do this work in Javascript, not Python, so you can avoid a round-trip to the server.